# CakePHP foreign key get column in conditions

Tags: php, cakephp

How does one use foreign table values from other columns in find SQL commands?

For example,

I now use such a construction:

```
$products = $this->Product->find('all');

$suits = array();

foreach ($products as $product) {
  if($product['ProductCategory']['name'] == "Suits"){
    array_push($suits,$product);
  }
}

$this->set('products',$suits);
```

Is it possible to transform this to something like:

```
$suits = $this->Product->find('list',array('conditions' => array('Products.ProductCategory.name' => "Suits")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = $this->Product->find('all', array('recursive' => -1,
                                              'contain'=>array('ProductCategory'=>
                                                  array('conditions'=>array('name'=>"Suits"))
                                 )));
```

That should filter all products by the category name and return

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Product] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                /*etc*/
            )
        [ProductCategory] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        /*etc*/
                    )
            )
    )
```